# How I can update the Field extensionAttribute3 with Powershell and System.Management.Automation in ASP.NET`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, active-directory, runspace

net application and I want to update informations in the active directory. For this I use the System.Management.Automation namespace. With this I can use the Powershell for this. It works good but I don't know how I can update the field "extensionAttribute3" (this is our Costcenter).

here my code:

```
...
 PSCredential crend = new PSCredential(ADNAME, pw);

                using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial))
                {
                    runspace.Open();
                    using (Pipeline p = runspace.CreatePipeline())
                    {
                        Command command = new Command("Set-ADUser");
                        command.Parameters.Add("Identity", sAMAccountName);
                        //command.Parameters.Add("extensionAttribute3", CostCenter); ??? 
                        command.Parameters.Add("Description", Description);
                        command.Parameters.Add("Credential", crend);

                        p.Commands.Add(command);

                        p.Invoke();

                    }
                }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The Set-ADUser cmdlet doesn't have a parameter for all the possible attributes.  For attributes that don't have dedicated parameter, you use the -Add, -Replace, and -Remove parameters and give them a hash table argument of the attribute names and values.  Not sure this if the syntax is exactly right, but something like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("Replace",@{extensionAttribute3='CostCenter'})
```